# font-awesome icons embedded in tcpdf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, tcpdf

I am building print-outs of my project using TCPDF. The output includes texts, tables and images. I want to embed font-awesome icons in TCPDF bootstrap style, for example:

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-warning fa-lg text-warning"></i>
```

The above line outputs an exclamation-mark (!) icon with bootstrap styles.
Can anybody tell me if this is possible? If it is, can you show me how.

Comment: Did you try converting/adding the FontAwesome font to your TCPDF, as documented here http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer to a pretty similar question on how to use the FontAwesome font in TCPDF:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44590235/3176753

Answer (score 2):

Font Awesome is using the CSS 'content' property to insert a character at the position of the `<i>` tag.

I don't think that CSS property is supported by TCPDF.

I added Font Awesome support using TCPDF's addTTFfont function then used code like:

```
<span style="font-family:FontAwesome;font-size: 2em;">&#xf0a4;</span>
```

instead of using the `<i>` tag. The hex code for the characters are in the CSS file of Font Awesome e.g.

```
.fa-hand-o-right:before {
    content: "\f0a4"
}
```

Comment: tried this using $html = '<span style="font-family:FontAwesome;font-size: 2em;">&#xf096;</span>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
 and nothing happened

Comment: @EvanR. you also need to add the Font Awesome font using addTTFfont

Comment: Could you tell me how you included the TTF font? I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Maybe post a question with example code. I guess you have seen http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

Comment: @MarkNZed, I am stuck into the issue: display Font Awesome icons in TCPDF. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Here are full steps (windows) how to use font awesome icons in PDF files rendered via TCPDF:

1. get TrueType file `FontAwesome.ttf`. This file needs to be compiled via TCPDF utility `tcpdf_addfont.php` supplied along with TCPDF. Format TTF can be downloaded along with other supplied web fonts e.g. EOT, WOFF, WOFF2, SVG - here for [version 4.7](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip) or [version 5](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web.zip).
2. place `FontAwesome.ttf` into directory `/tcpdf/tools/FontAwesome.ttf`. In this directory should be also the utility file `tcpdf_addfont.php`.
3. now I assume that your command line can work properly with PHP. Open command line console and type `php -v` to check if you have properly configured PHP CLI installation. If yes, you should see your PHP version output in console.
4. execute CLI command:

```
php ./tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueTypeUnicode -f 32 -i FontAwesome.ttf
```

This will execute PHP and compile `FontAwesome.ttf` into three output files, which will
be placed by default under `tcpdf/fonts/fontawesome.*`. Newly added files should be
`fontawesome.php`, `fontawesome.ctg.z` and `fontawesome.z`.

5. Use HTML methods for inserting icons into PDF:

```
// make sure "FontAwesome" is compiled truetype font family name 
// in compiled file `tcpdf/fonts/fontawesome.php` - find line name='FontAwesome';
$pdf->AddFont('FontAwesome', '');
$pdf->SetFont('FontAwesome', '', 14, '', true);

// following works:
$pdf->SetFont('FontAwesome');
$pdf->writeHTML("&#xf03e;"); // single icon
$pdf->writeHTML("2 icons: &#xf0a4; &#xf03e;"); // text "2 icons:" will show invalid chars
$pdf->writeHTMLCell("&#xf0a4;&#xf01d;&#xf03e;"); // three icons

// following does not work:
$pdf->SetFont('FontAwesome', '', 14, '', true);
// $pdf->Cell(0, 0, "\\xf0\xa4"); 
// $pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, "&#xf03e;");
// mixing up non-font awesome text and normal text does not work either
// $pdf->writeHTML("<span style='font-family:FontAwesome;'> &#xf0a4; </span>");

// after icons inserted, switch back to normal legible font
$pdf->SetFont('opensans', ''); 
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, "Continue normal text ..");
```

Final notes:

- inserting works only via **HTML methods** (`writeHtml`, `writeHtmlCell`). Could not figure out standard methods `Cell, MultiCell ..`.
- once you set `$pdf->SetFont('FontAwesome');` you **cannot mix up with normal legible text** - those characters will show up like non-legible squares.
- **turn off embedding only font subsets**. It appears that including only font subsets corrupts FontAwesome icons. Useful options:

```
// disallow font subsets for all fonts (before adding first page)
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false); 
// or disallow font subset only for font awesome (first load)
$pdf->SetFont('FontAwesome', '', 20, '', false);
```

- embedding `FontAwesome` adds to PDF filesize 55 kb (ver. 3.2.1) or 125 kB (ver. 4.7.0)

Comment: where do you get the FontAwesome.ttf file?

Comment: @bilogic I've updated 1. paragraph - TTF is normally supplied along with other formats (EOT, SVG, WOFF, ..) depending on FA version e.g. from https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

Comment: Do you have a matching TCPDF version for 4.7.0? I keep getting warnings `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 120 in vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_fonts.php on line 777` and the 3 output files are not usable. I mean, the files are there, but my PDF doesn't show the icon correctly.

Comment: @bilogic Did you follow steps above? You need to move 3 compiled files into folder with other fonts and then load into TCPDF e.g. `$pdf->SetFont('FontAwesome', '', 15, '', false);` and use inserting via HTML entities e.g. `$pdf->writeHTML("&#xf03e;");` - find your desired entity code in Font Awesome cheat table. There is no matching TCPDF version for 4.7.0 - steps above work generally for any FA version.

Comment: I currently have a set of the 3 files from a few years back that works with my TCPDF codes. Using `addTTFfont()`, then `writeHTML()` with `<span style="font-family: fontawesome; color: #{$inner_fill}" fill="true">&#xf111;</span>`, (`SetFont()` not required). But getting that `PHP Notice:` when running `tcpdf_addfont.php` now, and the generated files don't work. You don't get that notice?

Comment: do you mind if we open an issue to discuss on https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF ? It's hard to discuss on this comments section :)

Comment: @bilogic Feel free to open issue at TCPDF repo. But apparently you did not follow steps above - assuming from your comments. TCPDF parsing of inline CSS styles is limited, so setting inline "font-family: FontAwesome" will not load the font files. Please go step by step as written above with fresh new / empty PDF document - do not mix up with legacy issues. Isolate new procedure, then once it gets working, move back to legacy implementaion.

Comment: I have opened https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/370 and explained what's going on. I'm going to try your exact steps next and will update the results on #370. Thank you!

Comment: I have created this repo https://github.com/bilogic/fontawesome-tcpdf which uses your code. Same result. Could you share your working repo? or point out where I went wrong? Thank you.