# TCPDF font not embadding, showing "..." on adobe reader

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf

I added many fonts in `TCPDF` using this line of code

```
TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
$pdf->AddFont("ArchitectsDaughter");
```

Many other font is working but, this one is not working.
When i opening this pdf into reader, it shows error like this

> cannot extract the embedded font 'ArchitectsDaughter'. some character
>   may not display or print correctly.

I am importing `svg` file in pdf.
Here is the [SVG](http://printhubpro.co.uk/images/export.svg) file which i inserting in pdf, and you can get PDF from [here](https://www.printhubpro.co.uk/ajax/pdf) and here is the [font file](https://www.printhubpro.co.uk/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf).

Here is full code how pdf will generates.

```
$fileName='export';
$uploadPath = Config::get('constants.paths.uploads.images.base').'/'.$fileName.'.svg';

$pdf = new TCPDF();

TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/Archivor.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

$pdf->AddFont("Archivor");
$pdf->AddFont("ArchitectsDaughter");

$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->ImageSVG($uploadPath, $x='', $y='', $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);
$filename = 'export.pdf';
$pdf->output($filename, 'D');
exit;
```

Other fonts working ok for me. Don't know what happening with some fonts.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you import and use that font in your local system? So is it a valid and usable font file? Can you reference a download location for that file maybe for others here to test?

Comment: @arkascha i edited my question, you can see svg and pdf there. thanks for suggestion

Comment: I was asking about the font file, not any svg or pdf, since the error message suggests that the font file is corrupt.

Comment: @arkascha attached font also in question, apologize.

Comment: Hm, the font file appears valid on first sight, also I do _not_ get any error when opening the PDF. However the font does not sppear to be used inside that document... Could you please also post the relevant parts of your php code in the question? So the font file inclusion and usage?

Comment: i am just using these 2 lines to insert single font, i have too many other fonts also which including proper.
here is code which executes after font adding `$pdf->ImageSVG($uploadPath, $x='', $y='', $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);
     $filename = 'export.pdf';
     $pdf->output($filename, 'D');`

Comment: @arkascha i added code in question

Comment: Hm, I can't really spot where that font is used... If that really is the full code, that means the text I see in the PDF is part of the embedded SVG image? Hm, no idea if that SVG can refer to fonts embedded in a wrapping PDF document, never tried that. Also this might y very well depend in the PDF interpreter you are using. Which one is that? I ask especially because as said: I do _not_ get an error about the font file here using the Okular document viewer (PDF interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation `TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont()` adds the provided font permanently to the fonts folder and returns its name. So there is no reason to add it every time, but it is necessary to use added font with correct name.

```
// ...

$pdf = new TCPDF();

$fontArchitectsDaughter = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/font-awesome/fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
$fontArchivor = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/font-awesome/fonts/Archivor.ttf'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

$pdf->AddFont($fontArchivor);
$pdf->AddFont($fontArchitectsDaughter);

// ...
```

Comment: did same, but not worked for me. any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

First set up the font via `TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont()` or by adding the necessary files in the fonts dir (convert the TTF file via a TCPDF font converter like http://fonts.snm-portal.com)

After that, activate the font:

`$pdf->SetFont('FontAwesome','');`

Then, write a unicode character with the `writeHTML` function, starting with &#x and ending with ;
e.g.:  for the f0c9 (bars) icon (http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/):

`$pdf->writeHTML('&#xf0c9;');`